# Python pandas read_csv unable to read row properly because of double quotes in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a csv file (created in excel) with pandas read_csv. The format of the csv file is:

```
some text,some number,some text,some text,amount
SWE-WWW,123344422,Hello,SWE,"1,222.50 SEK"
SWE-W12,3124123412,Hello,SWE,450.50 SEK
```

My problem is that the quotation marks (") in the values in the "amount" column are causing the whole row to be read as a string and is put in the first column of the dataframe.

So when I read the csv file and print it:

```
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv', quotechar='"', sep=',')
print(test)
```

I get the output:

```
   some text    some number    some text.1    some text.2    amount
0  SWE-WWW,123344422,Hello,SWE,"1,222.50 SEK"  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  SWE-W12     3.124123e+09          Hello           SWE     450.50 SEK
```

As you can see pandas does not convert row 1 into a string since there are no quotation marks in the value in the "amount" column.

How can I read the csv file and get the data structured in the columns?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue on pandas 0.25. Try upgrading: `pip install --upgrade pandas`

Comment: Neither can I reproduce it with version 0.20.3.

Answer (score -1):

When reading CSV tp pandas it each column gets dtype (you can run `df.describe()`)
and a string is higher level then integer.
the highest level in `pandas` is `Object`.

you can run:

```
df['amount'] = df['amount'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
```

if you sure all column as digits